# How to expose ip address to kubernetes dashboard

Tags: bash, kubernetes, ip, kubernetes-dashboard, kubernetes-cluster

I set up a test k3s cluster in my local openstack machine and i want to access the dashboard from my local machine.

I followed this guide https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/web-ui-dashboard/
but didn't find the way to do it
I created 2 yaml files, 1 for a user and another one for permissions and was able to generate a token but i can't use it because i don't have and access to dashboard from my local machine

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.